# Unknown hinge type on ottoman chest

Tags: hinges, hardware-identification

I've got an old ottoman chest with a broken hinge. I'd like to replace it but don't know the name of the hinge type and my Google skills have failed me. The key part is the loop of metal that stops the hinge opening too far. I'm happy to hear if there's an alternative that can do the same job. The plywood the hinge is mounted to is 12mm/half inch in thickness.

[image: unknown hinge]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "stop hinge" or a "box hinge with stop". There are ones that have built-in soft close and/or lift function that mount on the inside of the box. Good if you want to replace those external surface mount ones with something a little nicer.